# Formatacao stdClassObject para array

Tags: php, array

Estou com um problema para converter alguns dados em meu sistema, tenho o seguinte trecho de codigo que retorna um array com um alguns objetos:

```
Array(
    [4014] => stdClassObject([id] => 4014[registro] => 9877[sigla] => total)
    [4006] => stdClassObject([id] => 4006[registro] => 9877[sigla] => Parcial)
)
```

Preciso converter estes objetos para um array para realizar o envio para um webservice no qual o padrao do webservice é este descrito abaixo:

**Objetivo Final :**

```
Array(
    [lista] => Array(
        [0] => Array(
            [registro] => 7069[sigla] => Parcial
        ) [1] => Array(
            [registro] => 7069[sigla] => Total
        ) 
    )
)
```

O que ja consegui implementar foi isto:

```
$dados = $DB->return_records($query);
foreach($dados as $dado) {
   $listagem['lista'][]= $dado;
}
```

E tem retornado o seguinte trecho:

```
Array(
    [lista] => Array(
                    [0] => stdClassObject([id] => 4014[registro] => 9877[sigla] => total)
                    [1] => stdClassObject([id] => 4006[registro] => 9877[sigla] => parcial)
                )
    )
```

Agora estou tentando gerar o resultado do bloco 2, mas ainda nao consegui, alguem poderia me auxiliar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Faça assim, tem de fazer o [cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5970270/how-to-cast-variable-to-array) de cada obj para array :

```
$dados = $DB->return_records($query);
foreach($dados as $dado) {
   $listagem['lista'][] = (array) $dado;
}
```

Comment: Vc é chato em Miguel Rsrsrs, era só isso kkkkkk.

Comment: :p chato?! porquê? @tkmattos

Comment: Pq foi muito rapido e cirurgico na resposta. Brigadao meu caro

Comment: hehe de nada @tkmattos, ainda bem que resolveu . Também já passei por isso muito, daí saber logo rápido

Comment: É o mal da tipagem do PHP KKKK

Comment: É verdade, também não gosto muito da sintaxe @tkmattos